# RF test socket pin max power handling capability

Tags: power, rf, test, socket

Do RF test socket pins have a max RF test power handling capability specification?
Most RF pins that these sockets touch do have this specification.  However, I don't see it listed for socket pins.  Wouldn't the metal alloy used to carry the RF power have to be able to withstand the max RF power?  Or am I missing something here?

A simple Google search for RF test sockets does not reveal max RF power handling capacity as a key specification.

Comment: Does this answer : https://www.centricrf.com/power-handling-connectors/  and this https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/coax-power-handling

Comment: Thanks.  This goes for a coax cable.  I am not sure if it applies to a test socket which may have metallic pins.  I appreciate your reply, though.

Comment: Ok. But what are then "RF test socket pins"?

Comment: These are the pins that make contact with a semiconductor device pads in the socket.

Comment: https://www.testfixtures.com/ic-test-sockets/?_vsrefdom=googleads&gclid=Cj0KCQjwhsmaBhCvARIsAIbEbH6X0WQcjkOpwcZas1W2oLKt6wmT19ztULCjRXYc5fVeUevb06glDj8aAkRWEALw_wcB

Comment: I am just surprised that there is no RF power handling capability spec for these sockets.  I would think that there should be one, just like the one for coax cables.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, did not know these ones.